# Angularjs calling function at regular interval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The problem is simply to reload the authentication token at regular interval. I am using `$interval` service for that. the code is as follows

```
function refresh_session() {
    console.log("testing");
}

module.exports = function ($scope,$rootScope,$localStorage,$location,$interval,$http) {

    $interval(refresh_session,5000);
```

This works just fine, but i need to access variables inside `$scope` and `$localStorage` to update the token. I have tried both passing a function defined inside `$scope` to `$interval` service as well as passing parameters to external function. Both of them are not working. What is the correct way i can go about that using the angular method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to place the `refresh_session` function inside your exported function? That would allow it to access that functions arguments. Like this:

```
module.exports = function ($scope,$rootScope,$localStorage,$location,$interval,$http) {

    $interval(refresh_session,5000);

    function refresh_session() {
        console.log("testing", $scope, $localStorage);
    }
    ...
};
```

Alternatively, you can have a function that creates the `refresh_session` function:

```
function refreshSessionCreator($scope, $localStorage){
    return function(){
        console.log("testing", $scope, $localStorage);
    };
}

module.exports = function ($scope,$rootScope,$localStorage,$location,$interval,$http) {

    $interval(refreshSessionCreator($scope, $localStorage),5000);
    ...
};
```